# Trying to automate a task

Tags: automation, ui-automation

I'd like to automate a task I'm doing but I'm not sure how to go about it.
this task requires me to go to a certain website and input a postal code and it shows me the names of the streets in this postal code, I have to copy the name and input the postal code and the street name into a search bar in a different website and a bunch of links appears that lead to a bunch of info and I have to screenshot that page also I need to check for dupes cause they may appear I'm not sure which language should I use or how to go about it I'm pretty new to coding and I would like some help.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like Selenium in Python to automate this task. You can use other languages too, but can you be more specific the next time you ask a question?